# How can I use a different distance measure for the k-nearest neighbor in Java/Weka?

Tags: weka, knn

I am using the k-nearest neighbor classifier on weka (http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/lazy/IBk.html).

I suppose the Euclidean distance is the default distance function. How could I change that function and use the same class with my own distance function?

Thanks,

Marco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IBk.getNearestNeighbourSearchAlgorithm().setDistanceFunction()` seems to be what you need.

Check out http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/DistanceFunction.html

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,

select ibk under lazy.
Click on ibk.
On the ibk detail page, click on the algorithm in the nearest neighbor search algorithm section, edit the distance function section on the screen.